# how to withdraw all tokens from the my contract in solidity after deployment?

Tags: solidity

I am deployed ERC-721 smart contract and sale was started and 3ETH in my contract
Now I am worried about how can I withdraw ETH from the contract to my wallet. How can I upgrade my contract with the withdrawal function?

Please help

Thanking in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

If the contract is already deployed with no withdraw function, no proxie, without a delegatecall, is very hard or imposible to withdraw the ether